# Magento Refresh admin specific tab

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, tabs

I want to refresh only a specific tab in Magento 1.X. For the moment I refresh the entire page with all tabs, but doing so I lose the infos from the other tabs.
What I have is in 1 tab I have 2 blocks, one is a grid where people do actions, and the other block is a simple form that has the summary, I want  the actions on the grid to refresh only the summary + grid in that tab only.